VMware SMbus host controller not enabled
My system bloated and I increased the available disk space, but it still wouldn't boot. I tried to increase the partition size via shell and nothing. It shows the usual piix SMBus related error message and the screen blacks out.
Error VMware SMbus host controller not enabled:

